# How to render a Blazor component into an HTML string

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I'm looking for a way to render a Blazor component into an HTML string, so that I'll be able to use it as a templating engine to create and send emails in my web application. Ideas?

Comment: Now there's an official solution coming with .NET 6: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68889811/1768303

Comment: @noseratio's link is dead now

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 the link still works for me, but here it is in its full form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889811/can-we-consume-a-blazor-component-as-a-web-component-within-a-regular-non-blazor

Comment: Works for me now, too.  Hrmmm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use the test library provided by Steve Sanderson and adapt it to your needs.
This article explains how to use it : [Introduction to Blazor Component Testing](https://chrissainty.com/introduction-to-blazor-component-testing/)
.
The library can be use to generate the HTML of a component.

exemple :

```cs
var host = new TestHost();
var component = host.AddComponent<YourComponent>();
var html = component.GetMarkup();
```

And you can inject services you need.

```cs
host.ConfigureServices(services => 
{
   service.AddSingleton<MyService>();  
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Agua's original answer is still good.. however

A new solution now available for this question: [BlazorTemplater](https://github.com/conficient/blazortemplater) is a library I wrote to address this capability (as I needed this for my app!).

This library will render any `.razor` component to HTML for use in emails. Supports nested components, properties, dependency injection, and can be used in Razor Component libraries.

Comment: Great solution, thanks

Comment: Link to official doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-custom-elements